# Use mini displayport as input on Windows or linux

Tags: linux, windows, video

I know mini displayport/thunderbolt can output video from my laptop, and can be similar to usb with some devices.

On Mac, there is/was a functionality that can turn your laptop as a screen for another mac through mini displayport.

Is there a way to use my laptop as a screen for other devices using mini display port as input ? Any softwares for displaying that input ?

Does a library can be used to read video stream on displayport? (I am ok with any langage if à library can do it)

Thanks in advance